# In exported csv value with number_format not showing with separated comma

Tags: php, php-7.2, export-csv

In my project, I am using the below code to format the number

```
$row[$k] = number_format($number, 2, '.', ',');
```

When I export the xlsx file it working properly and I am getting data like

> 2,607,697.14

But the issue is in csv. when I export the csv file I am getting data like

> 2607697.14

And If I am using below code

```
$row[$k] = '"' . number_format($number, 2, '.', ',') . '"';
```

For both csv and xlsx, I am getting

> "2,607,697.14"

I don't understand why I am not getting the value with comma in csv? And how I can get the value as I want?
Data display in csv file:

> Total Sales   Total Amount    Total Commission
>
> 234   2607697.14  148693.56

Data display in xlsx:

> Total Sales   Total Amount    Total Commission
>
> 234     2,607,697.14    148,693.56

Comment: Are you viewing the CSV file within Excel or within a text editor? Often spreadsheet programs like Excel will apply their own formatting by based on the data in the cell

Comment: Viewing both file in libreoffice(Ubuntu)

Comment: How looks like the exported line? Open the CSV file in text editor and copy paste here and example of several columns of exported data.

Comment: @ino updated with the both file content. Copy first 2 rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference between **CSV** and **XLS** file formats is that **CSV** format is a plain text format in which values are separated by commas, while XLS file format is an Excel Sheets binary file format which holds information about all the worksheets in a file.
So in **CSV** file you are getting numeric value as a plain text string but in **XLS** file same value shown as a formatted number.

In **XLS**, You can export image, links, symbols, charts but not in **CSV**.

Answer (score 0):

Simple
If the export code contains this

$objWriter->setDelimiter(',');
$objWriter->setEnclosure('');

please comment on it and try.